# Preivew of .pps formating is not generating in liferay

Tags: liferay, preview

I have configured openoffice for liferay and its working fine.I am able to see previews of .ppt formats but liferay is not producing any previews of ppt format.

Answer (score 0):

Okay as I was not able to find solution to this problem so what i did that i changed extension form .pps to .ppt a back end like as under

```
 String sourceFileName = file.getName();
 String mimeType =MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file);

  int index = sourceFileName.indexOf(".");
  String extension = sourceFileName.substring(index);
  String  name = sourceFileName.substring(0 ,index);

   if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".pps")){
       sourceFileName = name+".ppt";
   }

  String title = "title name";
  String description="desc of video";
  String changeLog = StringPool.BLANK;
  ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
  serviceContext.setAddCommunityPermissions(true);
  serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
  serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);

  DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(userId, repositoryId, folderId, sourceFileName, mimeType, title, description, changeLog, file, serviceContext);
```

and that worked for me abd its producing previews.I dont know if it is right way or not but its working for me.

Comment: [same here](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/30822245).